# SEO executive .htaccess file knowledge

Tags: seo, htaccess

Should SEO executive in a company have knowledge of `.htaccess` file to make changes in that file or it is the task of developer in the company to make even small changes? In short what I am asking is does the knowledge of `.htaccess` file lies in the domain of SEO work or not.

Comment: SEO is now a multi-disciplinary field. It involves development, writing, content creation, usability, IT, outreach, evangelism, and marketing.   It is not possible for one person to know everything in all these fields that could be useful for SEO.   An SEO executive may have a development background that would allow them to edit .htaccess, but they may have a very different background that would not make them suitable to that type of task.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Evangelism? I don't know any SEOs that do that... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> Should SEO executive in a company have knowledge of `.htaccess` file

Yes - to have some knowledge of `.htaccess`, where it fits in the development hierarchy and what you can do with it would be a good thing.

> ...to make changes

Probably not. A little knowledge could be disastrous. This is the role of the developer.

`.htaccess` (per-directory Apache config files) are not isolated units, they work together with the web application. You change one you might need to change the other. Would your "SEO executive" be diving into the application code itself to change URL structures, server-side caching, etc?

Company roles vary. You can have SEO guys who are experienced developers, and developers who have SEO knowledge, so it varies. But if your "SEO executive" is not fulfilling a developer role then they should only be advising, not actively developing.

Answer (score -2):

`.htaccess` is not the developer issue, This is the need and complete by Programmer. `.htaccess`use with Apache and web application, in SEO `.htaccess`we are using in URL rewriting, Redirection pages, 404 pages fix and some other tasks.